# How powerful would a series of rail guns or bombs need to be to destabilize a hurricane?

Tags: thermodynamics

In an effort to destabilize hurricanes by burning the necessary cold zones it has been proposed that planes drop various [carbon trash](http://www.dailygalaxy.com/my_weblog/2007/10/can-man-control.html) on them. That seems like a minor amount of heat change over a large area. What not just bomb the hurricane with remote detonation? How powerful would a series of rail guns or bombs need to be to destabilize a hurricane?

Comment: What does it mean to destabilize a hurricane? Storms are driven by gradients (in temperature or humidity or better yet entropy) between different altitudes and/or latitudes. When the gradients are steep enough, the atmosphere becomes *unstable* in that small flows build on themselves. Getting rid of storms amounts to either engineering a planet-wide method of calm equilibration (giant metal pipes everywhere?), or just doing away with the gradient altogether (permanently melt the ice caps perhaps?).

Comment: @ChrisWhite no hurricanes are dependant on a low pressure center other stuff. Landfall breaks them up and well as high pressure stuff.

Comment: Bombs would work by breaking up the wind currents;  last time I saw an estimate of this it would have taken enough nuclear devices to cause rather a nasty post- hurricane fallout problem.   BTW, the main reason landfall breaks them up is they can no longer harvest energy the way they do from open water.